# adding multiple content to homepage

Tags: theming, nodes

I am very new to Drupal. I want to add multiple content to my homepage,very simple,like this structure[image: Layout Homepage],I need to add two contents ,Main Content 1 and Main Content 2. I am able to add Main content 1 easily, but how can i add the main content 2 below the main content 1?. Will I be able to do it from the admin panel or I will need to change the theme structure?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily customize your theme depend upon your requirement

Open up your theme's .info file and you should see some regions like this:

regions[featured] = Featured

regions[content] = Content

regions[sidebar_first] = Sidebar first

regions[sidebar_second] = Sidebar second

to add a new region just type in a new one in that .info file. I'd be careful of replacing any though as there are several regions in D7 that are required.

Then you'll need to print out your new region in your page.tpl.php file which goes something like this now:

```
<?php if ($page['sidebar_first']): ?>
      <div id="sidebar-first" class="column sidebar"><div class="section">
        <?php print render($page['sidebar_first']); ?>
      </div></div> <!-- /.section, /#sidebar-first -->
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Don't forget to clear your cache or you won't see the new region. It really helps to poke around in some other D7 themes and see how they've done things also.

taken from this source http://drupal.org/node/1088718

Answer (score 0):

Many ways are there to create like this.

1. [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) module is used to design your home page like this.
2. [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module can create home page like this.
3. If you have good coding experience then you can define two region there and create two block for your content then use that block. You can use [node_level_blocks](http://drupal.org/project/node_level_blocks) to create node blocks.